# Subpages Not Redirecting Properly When Running Django on Bluehost

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, fastcgi, bluehost

We're setting up a testing environment for our Django application on Bluehost and having issues.

The main page loads fine, but clicking on any link cannot find the appropriate page (this is working fine on our localhost and production environment on Heroku).

**.htaccess file**

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteRule
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ /home2/naturbh2/public_html/dev/agile-atoll-6289/spicestore/SnapEDA.fcgi [QSA,L]
Options -Indexes
```

**.fcgi file**

```
#!/home2/naturbh2/python27/bin/python2.7
import sys, os
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home2/naturbh2/public_html/dev/agile-atoll-6289")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home2/naturbh2/public_html/dev/agile-atoll-6289/spicestore")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home2/naturbh2/public_html/dev/agile-atoll-6289/spicestore/apps")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home2/naturbh2/python27")

#print sys.path

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'spicestore.settings'
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Comment: what does your urls.py look like? What do some of the links in your pages that are directing the wrong way look like? Anything in settings.py that may also be causing it?

Comment: @AronYsidoro if any of these were the issue, I think that I'd be getting a similar experience on my localhost or production app on Heroku... Unless you can think of anything in those files that might be unique to running it with apache ..

Comment: What pages are your other links redirect to?